# How can I add an inline style in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to style inline the div `.trigger` on the following code and set its  display to block?

```
$('.trigger').toggle(function() {
   $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'}, 200);
}, function(){
   $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}, 200);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "on the following code" ?

Comment: You mean `$('.trigger').toggle(function(){}).css('display','block');` ?

Comment: JavaScript or JQuery? you might need to put the relevant tags in :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `$('.trigger').css('display', 'block');`

if you want to implement it inside your `toggle` function you can do something like this :

```
$('.trigger').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
    $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '300px', 'width': '400px'}, 200);
}, function(){
    $('.greendiv').animate({'height': '200px', 'width': '200px'}, 200);
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```